# How can I use Tkinter in a virtual environment?

Tags: python, tkinter, virtualenv

I want to use Tkinter in a virtual environment, but I have a problem: Tkinter is not included with the virtual environment.

On this site, I found a solution: adding the environment variable to the \scripts\activate.bat file. I did so, but it wasn't the solution for me.

I get the following while executing an example file:

```
(learning) c:\Users\jordy\python\learning>python simpleapp_tk.py                                          
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                      
  File "simpleapp_tk.py", line 4, in <module>                                                                           
    import Tkinter                                                                                 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'                                                                          

(learning) c:\Users\jordy\python\learning\sources>
```

What is the solution here? How can I make Tkinter working?

Comment: what version of python are you using in your virtual environment?

Comment: Try using `--system-site-packages` option when creating the environment.

Comment: @Himal No, that doesn't help.

Comment: @SierraMontainTech I use Python 3.6.1 :-)

Comment: @SierraMountainTech I use Python 3.6.1 :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python3, use `import tkinter` instead pf `import Tkinter`